# Как использовать repeatCount в Android AnimationSet?

Tags: android, xml, анимация

Как использовать repeatCount  в Android AnimationSet?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <scale
        android:duration="900"
        android:fromXScale="0"
        android:fromYScale="0"
        android:toXScale="1"
        android:toYScale="1"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="50%"/>

    <scale
        android:startOffset="1000"
        android:duration="200"
        android:fromXScale="1"
        android:fromYScale="1"
        android:toXScale="2"
        android:toYScale="2"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="50%"/>

    <alpha
        android:startOffset="500"
        android:duration="700"
        android:fromAlpha="1"
        android:toAlpha="0"/>
</set>
```

Почему то в Set repeat не работает. Как именно надо написать чтобы заработало?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

попробуйте воспользоваться таким вот классом слушателя анимации

```
public class AnimationRepeater implements Animation.AnimationListener
{
private View view;
private Animation animation;
private int count;

public AnimationRepeater(View view, Animation animation)
{
    this.view = view;
    this.animation = animation;
    this.count = -1;
}

public AnimationRepeater(View view, Animation animation, int count)
{
    this.view = view;
    this.animation = animation;
    this.count = count;
}

public void start()
{
    this.view.startAnimation(this.animation);
    this.animation.setAnimationListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) { }

@Override
public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation)
{
    if (this.count == -1)
        this.view.startAnimation(animation);
    else
    {
        if (count - 1 >= 0)
        {
            this.animation.start();
            count --;
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) { }
}
```

для бесконечного цикла использовать:

```
Animation a = AnimationUtils(Context, R.anim.animation);
new AnimationRepeater(View, a).start();
```

если необходимо кстановить количество повторов:

```
Animation a = AnimationUtils(Context, R.anim.animation);
new AnimationRepeater(View, a, int N).start();
```

где N - количество повторов анимаций

Answer (score -1):

```
<scale
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:duration="1000"
    android:repeatCount="infinite"
    android:repeatMode="reverse"
    android:fromXScale="0.75"
    android:fromYScale="0.75"
    android:toXScale="1"
    android:toYScale="1"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%" />
```

IDE давно не реагирует на 2 тега в схеме, но они инфлейтятся, просто пропишите ручками, как выше.

```
android:repeatCount
android:repeatMode
```

Анимашка будет работать что-то типо wave эффекта, сами запустите. Но и вариант указать сеттерами и геттерами, тоже все работаете, если анимашка не поломана.

Comment: Если вы внимательноей присмотрите к анимации, то поймете что не вариант использовать 
android:repeatCount="infinite"
    android:repeatMode="reverse".

Внутри каждого действия. ПОтому что у них время разное.